# Reading parameters from DJI drone

Tags: ios, swift, dji-sdk

I have to make an iOS application for DJI family of drones, in Swift.

I went to the official web page, successfully integrated the SDK via CocoaPods, but I do have couple of questions:

- How to get the current altitude of the aircraft?
- How to get the current distance?
- How to get the current speed?
- Is there any way to read the internal memory size of the aircraft and what's the remaining space?

I've also managed to get the GPS signal via `DJIFlightControllerState`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the link to the method for [Altitude](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController_DJIFlightControllerCurrectState.html?search=altitude&i=0&#djiflightcontroller_djiflightcontrollercurrectstate_aircraftlocation_inline)

To get the distance between the aircraft and some other point (ie the RC or Homepoint) you will need to get the [Latitude and Longitude](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController_DJILocationCoordinate2D.html) of all the points and use your own logic to calculate the distance from each. You can check out the [Android Location class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location) to accomplish this.  Or you can use a widget in our UXSDK: [DUXDistanceRCWidget](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-uilib-api/Widgets/DistanceFromRCWidget.html?search=distance&i=0&#distancefromrcwidget_distance_inline)
or the [DUXDistanceHomeWidget](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-uilib-api/Widgets/DistanceFromHomeWidget.html?search=distance&i=1&#distancefromhomewidget_distance_inline)

To get the speed of the aircraft is a similar concept - you can use our method getVelocity under [FlightControllerState](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController_DJIFlightControllerCurrectState.html) class for X,Y,Z and calculate the speed. Or again, we have a [velocity widget](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-uilib-api/Widgets/HorizontalVelocityWidget.html?search=vel&i=1&#horizontalvelocitywidget_velocityvalue_inline) in our UXSDK

To get memory size of your SD card you can look at the class [mediaFile](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Camera/DJIMediaManager_DJIMedia.html?search=memory&i=3&#djimediamanager_djimedia_resetpreview_inline) however information on the memory of the drone itself is not made available.